# Avoid variable expansion in zsh

Tags: zsh

If I use the zsh shell and execute the following command I get

```
$zsh
$echo '$_GET["test"]'
preexec: bad math expression: operand expected at `"test"'

$echo '$_GET[]'
preexec: invalid subscript
```

In bash I get what I expect:

```
$bash
$echo '$_GET["test"]'
$_GET["test"]
```

I assume that zsh is trying to expand the $_GET variable. How can I avoid this? I always expected this to only happen within double quotes anyhow.

**[update]**
I found the following three lines in the .zshrc:

```
# Display last command interminal
echo -en "\e]2;Parrot Terminal\a"
preexec () { print -Pn "\e]0;$1 - Parrot Terminal\a" }
```

After commenting them out everything seems to work as expected.
What I understand is that preexec is executed after a command in the terminal has been submitted but before it is executed. The $1 is the command that one submitted.

I still do not understand the purpose of the two lines but is it because of the double quotes in the preexec print statement that the variables are expanded?

Comment: Use `zsh -f` to start a 'clean' zsh shell, and you should see the results you expect. It looks like something in your `zsh` environment is adding a [preexec hook](https://github.com/rothgar/mastering-zsh/blob/master/docs/config/hooks.md) that is producing the error.

Comment: As one can clearly see, the error message obviously comes from `preexec`, not the `echo` statement. You did not provide the definition of your _preexec_ hook, so no diagnosis is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `print -P` together with the expansion of `$1` is killing you. With this, you first get a "normal" expansion of $1, yielding something like `"\e]0;echo '$_GET["test"]'..."`. Now `-P` causes `print` to do a prompt expansion on this string, which means that it has to expand `$_GET["test"]` as well. This causes the error.

I suggest to remove the `-P`, in particular since you don't have any characters in your string which would benefit from prompt expansion.